# Sumar array en un controlador

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un array en un controlador, necesito agregar un campo nuevo llamado `total` sumar los valores de los campos `amount` para obetner el total, tengo lo siguiente:

```
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
    {
        Badge::create([
            'user_id' => $id,
            'shop' => $request['shop'],
            'payment_number' => $request['payment_number'],
            'code' => $request['code'],
            'currency' => $data['currency'][$i],
            'serial' => $data['serial'][$i],
            'amount' => $data['amount'][$i],
            'status' => 0,
        ]);
    }
```

Estoy intentando con esto pero no funciona:

```
$total = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
    {
        $total = $total + $data['amount'][$i];
        Badge::create([
            'user_id' => $id,
            'shop' => $request['shop'],
            'payment_number' => $request['payment_number'],
            'code' => $request['code'],
            'currency' => $data['currency'][$i],
            'serial' => $data['serial'][$i],
            'amount' => $data['amount'][$i],
            'total' => $total,
            'status' => 0,
        ]);
    }
```

Cambios realizados:

```
$sum = $data['amount'];
$total = array_sum($sum);

for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
    {
        Badge::create([
            'user_id' => $id,
            'shop' => $request['shop'],
            'payment_number' => $request['payment_number'],
            'code' => $request['code'],
            'currency' => $data['currency'][$i],
            'serial' => $data['serial'][$i],
            'amount' => $data['amount'][$i],
            'total' => $total,
            'status' => 0,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: puedes decir que vale `$c`?

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Ya solucioné parcialmente, lo sumé así: `$sum = $data['amount']; $total = array_sum($sum);` pero no recibo el valor del total dentro de `Badge::create`

Comment: Imprimo fuera del `Badge::create` la variable `$total` con `dd($total)` y funciona, pero no la recibo dentro del `Badge::create`

Comment: Actualizada la pregunta!

Comment: Resuelto, faltaba agregar el campo total en el Modelo! gracias!

Comment: Okey, Perfecto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución fue la siguiente, en el controllador hice este cambio:

```
$sum = $data['amount'];
$total = array_sum($sum);

for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
{
    Badge::create([
        'user_id' => $id,
        'shop' => $request['shop'],
        'payment_number' => $request['payment_number'],
        'code' => $request['code'],
        'currency' => $data['currency'][$i],
        'serial' => $data['serial'][$i],
        'amount' => $data['amount'][$i],
        'total' => $total,
        'status' => 0,
    ]);
}
```

Y en el modelo, agregué el campo `total`, que no lo había hecho.